# Why eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$ are in row space of $\mathbf{A}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

I'm following SVD proof and I can't get why eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$ are in rowspace of $\mathbf{A}$. I can understand further why these eigenvectors are basis for the row space of $\mathbf{A}$, if they are in the row space of  $\mathbf{A}$, but I miss this very step of proof about belonging to the rowspace of $\mathbf{A}$. I know it must be very simple, so the books I use don't specify it or specified it earlier in the book.

Comment: Hint: what is the relation of the row space of $\mathbf A$ and the column space of $\mathbf A^{\mathrm T}$?

Comment: They are the same

Comment: If $\mathbf A ^{\mathrm T} \mathbf A \mathbf v = \mathbf A^{\mathrm T}(\mathbf {Av}) = c \mathbf v$, then where does $\mathbf v$ belong now?

Comment: Oh, I see, $\mathbf{v}$ belong to row space of $\mathbf{A}$ and column space of $\mathbf{A}^T$. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer of @xbh given in the comments above:

> If $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{A}^T(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{v}) = c\mathbf{v}$ then $\mathbf{v}$ belongs to the row space of $\mathbf{A}$ and the column space of $\mathbf{A}^T$.

Comment: This assumes $c \ne 0$. Though I guess the question is only for non zero eigenvalued eigenvectors

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf A$ be a matrix; then $\forall \boldsymbol x$, $\mathbf A \boldsymbol x$ is in the column space of $\mathbf A$.
Thus $\mathbf A^T (\mathbf A \boldsymbol v)$ is in the column space of $\mathbf A^T$.
But $\mathbf A^T \mathbf A \boldsymbol v = c \boldsymbol v$.
Hence $c \boldsymbol v$ (or $\boldsymbol v$ if $c \ne 0$) is also in the column space of $\mathbf A^T$.

Comment: Your answer would be a fine alternative to the accepted answer, except for the pointless opening remark.